AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute load_dataset
I am engaging a project now, and the library utils might be frequently used. However, I encounter a problem.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import utils 

images, labels = utils.load_dataset()

weights_input_to_hidden = np.random.uniform(-0,5, 0,5 (20,784))
weights_hidden_to_output = np.random.uniform(-0,5, 0,5 (10,20))
bias_input_to_hidden = np.zeros((20,1))
bias_hidden_to_output = np.zeros((10,1))

how to solve this guys?
I tried to install in the terminal via pip utils, but nothing worked

The utils package from pip doesn't have a load_dataset() function. If you have your own utils.py file that has a load_dataset() function then this file isn't seeing it and you need to either place it in the same directory or alter the import path to reach it.

Thanks, but could you explain in more detail or with an example how to do this?

I tried to install "dataset" via cmd by entering "pip install dataset" into the folder where my python project is stored

I don't really know what you expect the dataset to do. The problem is that you don't have a load_dataset() method anywhere it seems, so the interpreter doesn't know what to do when you try to use that function. Do you use the images or labels variables at all? If not you can just remove that line entirely.
